# jquery validation error multiple fields 1 custom error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I've looked around on Stack to try and find a solution to a problem that I've encountered with my jQuery validation. I've decided to change my error messages, that were below my input fields to a **single** generic all encompassing message placed above the form.
I have a class **"hide"** on that message **"#error_mail"** that I want to replace with **"error"** when there is an error in the field(s) on submission/validation. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="new_web_user" id="new_web_user" autocomplete="off">
            <p class="fields-required">
            *Required fields</p>
            <p id="error_mail" class="hide">We&#39;re sorry, the fields highlighted in red are required</p>
            <div class="field-column"> etc etc.....
```

JS

```
$(function(){jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
             errorContainer: "#error_mail",
             errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
             error.appendTo('#error_mail');
      },
             ignore: ':hidden:not([class~=selectized]),:hidden > .selectized, .selectize-control .selectize-input input'
      });

    $('#new_web_user').validate({
              rules: {
                  web_user_title: {required: true},
                  web_user_given_name: {
                    required: true
                 },
                  web_user_family_name: {
                    required: true
                 },                  
                  web_user_email: { 
                    required:   true,
                    email:      true
                 },
                 email_confirmation: {
                    required:   true,
                      equalTo: '#web_user_email'
                 },
                 web_user_country: {
                    required:   false,
                 },
              },
              messages : {
                 web_user_title:     {
                        required: "Please select a title."
                 },
                 web_user_given_name:    {
                        required: "Firstname is required."
                 },
                 web_user_family_name:   {
                        required: "Lastname is required."
                 },
                 web_user_email:     {
                        required: "Email address is required.",
                        email: "Email address seems invalid."
                 },
                 email_confirmation:     {
                        required: "Email address is required.",
                        equalTo: "Email addresses do not match."
                 },
                 web_user_country:   {
                        required: "Please choose your country."
                 }
             },
             submitHandler:  function(form) {
                $.ajax({
```

Comment: What's not working? What is the question? Can you provide a codepen?

Comment: @james-g I've figured out, probably messily how to add the error labels to my chosen container #error_mail, but could you help me figure out how to change the class that I have on the <P>. What I want is the class, which is "hide" currently  to replace with "error" when there are errors in the form. And then return to "hide" when the form is valid. Codepen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this a lot, using the options available in jQuery Validate:

```
$("#new_web_user").validate({
    errorContainer: '#error_mail',
    errorLabelContainer: '#actual_errors',
    wrapper:'li',
    //your rules and messages here
});
```

Then, change your HTML to be something more like this:

```
<p id="error_mail" class="hide error">
  We&#39;re sorry, the fields highlighted in red are required 
  <ul id="actual_errors"></ul>
</p>
```

Note that instead of adding/removing the error class you want on `#error_mail`, just set it at all times, as it will only be visible when there is a problem...

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/cayjuwf4/